# WCF calls 3rd party DLL only works in VS2015 but not without

Tags: c#, wcf, iis, visual-studio-2015, iis-express

I am using 64bit Windows7 home premium SP1 and VS2015.

I wrote a WCF application which calls a 3rd party dll (from vendor) written in C#. When i "view in browser" by right clicking ProductREADService.svc in VS2015 solution explorer, I can call the svc(localhost:17476/ProductRESTService.svc) and method(this calls the 3rd party dll localhost:17476/ProductRESTService.svc/getproductlist/1) and the WCF works without any problem on the browser (chrome and IE), returning xml result correctly.

Now I want this WCF to running without VS2015 since I need it to run in production env.

Problem:

1)
However, when I publish this WCF to IIS7.5, I was able to call the svc (localhost:8123/ProductRESTService.svc) without problem, but when I called the method (localhost:8123/ProductRESTService.svc/getproductlist/1) I encountered request error "The server encountered an error processing the request. See server logs for more details."
When I checked the logs I found this: 
2016-09-07 12:46:44 ::1 GET /favicon.ico - 8123 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 404 0 2 3
2016-09-07 12:48:26 ::1 GET /ProductRESTService.svc/getproductlist/1 - 8123 - ::1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/52.0.2743.116+Safari/537.36 400 0 0 4

I tried changing the DefaultAppPool identity to LocalService and my windows login ID, nothing works.

In order to confirm the problem lies with the 3rd party DLL, I changed the method getproductlist not to load/call the 3rd party DLL but instead return fixed dummy value, and now both works perfectly. So I am sure the problem is caused by the DLL when running without VS2015.

2) I reverted back the code and stopped IIS and tried running IISExpress (using the IISexpress used by vs2015). I started it using the same config file as VS2015 inside  /config:path-to-code.vs\config\applicationhost.config... I encountered the exactly same issue, while accessing localhost:17476/ProductRESTService.svc there is not problem.. BUT encountered error when accessing the method localhost:17476/ProductRESTService.svc/getproductlist/1.

Question:

q1) how come the WCF calling 3rd party DLL only works when launched using VS2015 and not when launched via IIS7.5 or IISexpress independently?

q2) how to copy the IISexpress settings/config from VS2015 into IIS7.5 and to the c:\program files\IIE Express\IISexpress.exe?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

**Update:** 
2) I found the problem for IISExpress.. I changed to "C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS Express\iisexpress.exe" instead of "C:\Program Files\" and both svc and method work! Why not "C:\Program Files" since my OS is 64bit?

I still cant get IIS to work for both, any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you install IIS on your local machine and see if you can configure it there? Most likely it's not finding the 3rd Party dll. Does it need to be installed? Is the path the same?

Comment: Yes both the IIS and IISexpress are on local PC. And weird thing is the IISexpress website (port 17476) works perfectly only when i run it with VS2015. When I ran IISexpress (port 17476) from commandline without VS2015, only the svc worked... the getproductlist method doesnt work.

Answer (score 1):

**Update Solved!**

I managed to fix the problem. In IIS 7.5.76 I set the **DefaultAppPool** advanced settings to

1) .NET Framework Version v4.0

2) Enable 32-bit application = true

3) Identity = LocalSystem

Now, my WCF service and method(calling 3rd party DLL) works with IIS and I can run it as a production service!